# Why does this.tail change the property of this.head in my Linkedlist class?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, linked-list, this

Consider a LinkedList class which mimics the Linkedlist data structure as below:

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    };
    this.tail = this.head;
    this.length = 1;
  }
  append(value) {
    const newNode = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail.next = newNode; // why does this change head.next ?
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }
}

let myLinkedList = new LinkedList(10);
myLinkedList.append(5);
```

log output

```sh
LinkedList {
  head: { value: 10, next: { value: 5, next: null } },
  tail: { value: 5, next: null },
  length: 2
}
```

I see that `this.tail.next` will change the next property of tail as well (then `this.tail = newNode` will reassign tail to newNode). What I don't understand here is why `this.tail.next` would also change the next property of this.head?

Also, when appending another number to the list `myLinkedList.append(16)`, it keeps updating the next property of head as below:

```sh
LinkedList {
  head: { value: 10, next: { value: 5, next: [Object] } },
  tail: { value: 16, next: null },
  length: 3
}
```

Maybe a possible reason relates to the constructor where I define `this.tail = this.head`? But I'm not really sure since this one only assigns value of head to tail.

To sum up, my question is why does `this.tail.next = newNode` change the next property of the head? Also, when appending another value, why does it change head.next.next and so on?

Comment: "*Maybe a possible reason relates to the constructor where I define `this.tail = this.head`?*" - yes, of course that's the reason: both properties now hold the same object reference, and then you're changing the `.next` property of that object referenced from both places.

Comment: The first append is _expected_ to update head (because at the beginning head _is_ tail). The second append doesn't update `head`, it's just `console.log` that represents it this way. That is, your code is fine.

Comment: (The only thing that's weird about your code is that the linked list always consists of at least one element and cannot be empty)

Comment: This is not my code (yeah it is supposed to work this way but I didn't understand how it worked so I asked : D (after some thinking tbh) ) So actually it's just object reference. The reference object of head is assigned to tail. when I do `tail.next` it also updates the object it references to which is the head.next. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the constructor has run, `this.tail` and `this.head` reference the same object, so any assignment you make to `this.tail.next` is visible in `this.head`, since that really is a reference to the same object that is being mutated.

It may help to visualise this. Once the constructor has run, we have this situation:

```
     this.head
      ↓          
    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 10 │
    │ next: null│
    └───────────┘
      ↑
     this.tail
```

Then `append(5)` will first create a new node:

```
     this.head        newNode
      ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 10 │    │ value: 5  │
    │ next:null │    │ next:null │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
      ↑
     this.tail
```

Then `this.tail.next = newNode;` is executed, which is a modification of that `next` property in the first object:

```
     this.head        newNode
      ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 10 │    │ value: 5  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next:null │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
      ↑
     this.tail
```

So indeed, this also changes `this.head.next`... because it is just the very same property.

Then `this.tail = newNode;` is executed:

```
     this.head        newNode
      ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 10 │    │ value: 5  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next:null │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
                       ↑
                      this.tail
```

The next time `append` is called, the `next` property of the *second* object will be updated, and so we get:

```
     this.head                         newNode
      ↓                                 ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 10 │    │ value: 5  │    │ value: 16 │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next:null │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
                                        ↑
                                       this.tail
```

And yes, this change is also traceable from `this.head`, because... it is a linked list... so it *should* be traceable. As each `next` property refers to the next node, you can find your way from `head` to any of the nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your easy to understand illustration! I really appreciate it!